# confidence interval for segmented glm

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to fit a segmented glm to some data:

```
x <- c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2,2.25,2.5,2.75,3,3.25)
y <- c(5.516,5.725,5.9781,6,6.453,6.88,7.3,11,11.89,15.6,21.3,27,32.8)
d <- data.frame(x = x,
                y = y)

if(!require("segmented")) {
  install.packages("segmented")
  require("segmented")
}

g1 <- glm(y ~ x,data = d)
g2 <- segmented(g1, seg.Z = ~ x,
                psi = list(x = c(1.5)))
pdat <- data.frame(x = d$x,
                   y = broken.line(g2, link = FALSE)[,1])
pdat <- pdat[with(pdat, order(x)), ]
plot(y ~ x, data = d, pch = 21, bg = "white")
lines(y ~ x, data = pdat, type = "l", col = "red")
```

[image]

I would now like to draw confidence intervals around the segmented line, but have no idea on how to do this. I can draw confidence intervals for a non segmented plot:

```
## use quadratic function
g3 <- lm(y ~ poly(x, 2), data = d)
pdat <- with(d, data.frame(x = exp(seq(min(x),
                                         max(x), length = 100))))

tmp2 <- predict(g3, newdata = pdat, se.fit = TRUE)
critVal <- qt(0.975, df = g3$df.residual)
pdat <- transform(pdat, pred = tmp2$fit, se = tmp2$se.fit)
pdat <- transform(pdat, yhat = pred,
                   upr = pred + (critVal * se),
                   lwr = pred - (critVal * se))
plot(y ~ x, data = d)
lines(yhat ~ x, data = pdat, type = "l", col = "red") # gam model
lines(upr ~ x, data = pdat, type = "l", lty = "dashed", col = "red") # upper limit
lines(lwr ~ x, data = pdat, type = "l", lty = "dashed", col = "red") # lower limit
```

[image]

But when I repeat this for the segmented version it doesn't seem quite right:

```
# repeat same method for segmented
g1 <- glm(y ~ x,data = d)
g2 <- segmented(g1, seg.Z = ~ x,
                psi = list(x = c(1.5)))
pdat <- with(d, data.frame(x = exp(seq(min(x),
                                       max(x), length = 100))))

tmp2 <- predict(g2, newdata = pdat, se.fit = TRUE)
critVal <- qt(0.975, df = g2$df.residual)
pdat <- transform(pdat, pred = tmp2$fit, se = tmp2$se.fit)
pdat <- transform(pdat, yhat = pred,
                  upr = pred + (critVal * se),
                  lwr = pred - (critVal * se))
plot(y ~ x, data = d)
lines(yhat ~ x, data = pdat, type = "l", col = "red") # gam model
lines(upr ~ x, data = pdat, type = "l", lty = "dashed", col = "red") # upper limit
lines(lwr ~ x, data = pdat, type = "l", lty = "dashed", col = "red") # lower limit
```

[image]

So, my first question is why does the quadratic function not extend to the entire x axis i.e. why does it stop at 1.25? Secondly, is the method that I've followed for confidence intervals for the segmented line correct, or is there a better method for this?

Comment: Why don't you set `interval = "confidence"` in `predict`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this? Band represents 95% CI.

```
x <- c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2,2.25,2.5,2.75,3,3.25)
y <- c(5.516,5.725,5.9781,6,6.453,6.88,7.3,11,11.89,15.6,21.3,27,32.8)
d <- data.frame(x = x,
                y = y)

mdl <- glm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3), data = d)

prd <- predict(mdl, newdata = d[, "x", drop = FALSE], se = TRUE)
d$fit <- prd$fit
d$lci <- d$fit - 1.96 * prd$se.fit
d$uci <- d$fit + 1.96 * prd$se.fit

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, ymin = lci, ymax = uci)) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(aes(x = x, y = fit), stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: this does not use the segmented glm function in the OP though, does it?

Comment: Of course it doesn't, but it describes the data, @Kate.

Comment: Yes, great. But I'm looking for a method for doing this using the segmented glm. The exponential function used in the question what just to illustrate how I determine the confidence interval for that method

Answer (score 2):

Buildin on @Roman's answer, here is a similar apporach , that may perhaps closer to what your looking for:

```
x <- c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2,2.25,2.5,2.75,3,3.25)
y <- c(5.516,5.725,5.9781,6,6.453,6.88,7.3,11,11.89,15.6,21.3,27,32.8)
d <- data.frame(x = x,
                y = y)
d$thing <- c(rep("a",8), rep("b",5))

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(d, aes(x = x, y = y, group = thing)) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_bw() +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ I(x^2) + I(x^3),
              fill = NA, linetype = 3, geom = "ribbon", colour = "red") +
  stat_smooth(method = "lm", formula = y ~ I(x^2) + I(x^3),
              fill = "transparent", colour = "black")
```

[image]